# Create a Pivot Chart which compares an individual's score with that of his teams Average score

Tags: excel, pivot, pivot-table, pivot-chart

I need to compare how Fred is performing compared to the rest of his team `Team 1` in the form of Pivot Line Graph. Below is the data.

```
A         B         C        D
James     Team 1    20   11/05/18
Fred      Team 1    50   12/11/18
Elliott   Team 2    100  21/04/18
Sarah     Team 1    75   11/04/18
Fred      Team 1    75   11/04/18
```

I need to create a Pivot Table from this data and then a Pivot Chart which shows a line graph for Team 1 and a line graph overlaid for Fred. The Team scores would be the average i.e. total of C Team As / No. of Team As.

The chart would have slicers attached to other Charts where a different Name or possible Team could be selected to filter.

I can create a chart for the names or for the teams but weighing a name against the team aggregate doesn't look possible.

Comment: line graph is used to show continuity or a continuous value entity, i think you should go for a bar graph. In your statement "which shows a line graph for Team 1 and a line graph overlaid for Fred" these would be two points (average of team 1 and points of Fred) how you want to create a line graph for them.

Comment: Sorry I didn't add that there would be a column D with date values.

Comment: one date for one person doesn't make it continuous, it is still a point.

Comment: There would be more than one date per person. There would be thousands with same names repeated. This is why it would need to be a Pivot Chart and not a standard graph.

Comment: Can you update your question to show sample of your data with date

Comment: Updated. On mobile at the moment but can add more data later if there is still trouble understanding it.

Comment: i believe team average should be the average scores for that day not an overall score average. Is it correct?

Comment: Yes, average score of each team for each day.

Comment: at least let me know if it solved your problem or not, for me no answer means i have wasted my time.

Comment: Thanks @usmanhaq. I've not had the time yet to go over your solution. It looks good and should work. I just need to apply it to my own data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok here it is, let me know if it solves your problem

[image]

Formula in E2 is

```
=AVERAGE(IF($B$2:$B$26=B2,IF($C$2:$C$26=C2,$D$2:$D$26)))
```

It is an array formula and have to be entered using Ctrl+Shift+Enter

The pivot table is as below

[image]

and the graph looks like this

[image]

Here is the pivot options window

[image]